# Apps for making geometric shapes (math)

Tags: applications, software-recommendation

Is there any apps for making geometric shapes (math)? I need to make shapes like rhombus and equilateral triangles.

I have already posted this in the [math forum](https://math.stackexchange.com/), but I think this is more related to apple.

Comment: Have You tried OSX builtin `Grapher.app` ?

Comment: and do you mean Illustrator? Or more something like R?

Comment: Something with a drag and drop interface. I have never used R. Is it something like that?

Answer (score 1):

## Grapher.app

You might want to take a look at /Application/Utilities/Grapher.app. It is a graphical calculator that can create 2D and 3D shapes.

x<sup>2</sup>y<sup>2</sup>z<sup>2</sup>=42

[image]

Here is a starters tutorial that looks fine: http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-grapher-your-macs-built-in-graph-tool--mac-48440

Answer (score 0):

**Omnigraffle**

If You want to use drag'n'drop solution I can recommend Omnigraffle https://www.omnigroup.com/omnigraffle. It's very powerful but not free. You can get additional stencils from https://www.graffletopia.com.